# [[Class]] property in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

The `[[Class]]` property of object is set according to how an object is created IIUC.

Is this why some objects are rendered to the Chrome console in a meaningful way e.g. `MyFoo` and others are simply rendered as `Object`?

With the new object literal syntax in ES6 for configuring the prototype chain.  Can I modify the `[[Class]]` property of the resulting object, so that it is rendered in a more meaningful way to the console?

```
var x = { __proto__: MyCtor.prototype };
console.log(x); // I want something like MyCtor to be logged to the console
```

I note that in Safari 8 on a Mac the above renders `MyCtor` to the console. Chrome on the Mac does not.

PS: perhaps this is due to my confusing of browsers that support this prototype chain initialization syntax.

Comment: There is no `[[Class]]` in ES6 afaik.

Comment: @elclanrs OK thanks make this the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: No, afaik the `[[Class]]` has never affected how `console.log` displays objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I modify the `[[Class]]` property of the resulting object

Well, there is a trick here. The internal property `[[Class]]` has been removed in ES-6. But, the only way to get the value from `[[Class]]` was the `Object.prototype.toString.call` method. Now, you can customize that to return whatever name you want. Quoting the [draft version of ECMA Script 6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring),

> 16. Let tag be `Get (O, @@toStringTag)`.
> 17. `ReturnIfAbrupt(tag)`.
> 18. If `Type(tag)` is not `String`, let `tag` be `builtinTag`.
> 19. Return the String that is the result of concatenating `"[object ", tag, and "]"`.

So, if we can change the `@@toStringTag`, we can actually change result of `Object.prototype.toString.call`. We change it like this

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    get: function() {
        return "MyClass";
    }
});

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
# [object MyClass]
```

**Note:** The above seen program is tested in iojs (v1.0.2 with --harmony flags enabled).

Comment: With computed properties, this can even be simplified to `var obj = {[Symbol.toStringTag]: "MyClass"};`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no [[Class]] in ES6, there are [intrinsic objects](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects).

Answer (score 1):

If you would use Object.prototype.toString.call(x), where x is any built-in class instance, then it would give you results like [object Array], [object Function], given that x is instance of array, function etc. But if x is an object of a user defined class, then this would simply return [object Object]. To overcome this, we can define a [Symbol.toStringTag] property in that user defined class's prototype, which returns a string to describe the object type, and when we use Object.prototype.toString(), it looks for this method first in the argument.

```
class CustomClass {
  constructor() {}
}
CustomClass.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'CustomClass';
const obj = new CustomClass();
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
```

This would result in output [[object CustomClass]].
But you might be wondering that since Object.prototype.toString.call() works for built-in types, then classes like Array, Function might already have this [Symbol.toStringTag] which this Object.prototype.toString is using, but if you log Array.prototype, there is no such method defined.
So for the built-in types, Object.prototype.toString() actually looks for an internal property which is [[class]] to determine the type of the object.